# What is the simplest layout to choose to make book finder app?

Tags: android, android-layout, prototyping

I want to make very simple book finder app for a website.

The prototype is this(how i want it to look like):

[image: prototype]

I have chosen grid layout, but the search field keeps jumping around, i think the problem is the layout(maybe wrong)

[image: layout]

**Question: what layout do you recommend for this simple app?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridLayout or TableLayout will work fine, but you can also use a combination of LinearLayout (one vertical and one horizontal).

If your app stays simple, it is easier to use LinearLayout.

I am not sure I answered your question.